# Working with S3, AWS Lambda, Python 3.10 & .xlsx file

Tags: python-3.x, excel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, xlsx

I have a .xlsx file in a subfolder inside a bucket. This excel file has many tabs (9 tabs). I want to load each of these tabs (some filtered data) into individual data frames and save those data frames into corresponding sheets in another excel file present in another subfolder/bucket. I had implemented this successfully using just python and the file residing in a folder within  my PC. But I am not able to figure out how to work on specific sheet names using AWS Lambda (Python) and S3. The below code currently errors out with "[ERROR] ValueError: embedded null byte"

I have created layers and have added the relevant packages for AWS Lambda (for packages like pandas,openpyxl,xlsxwriter etc.) but the targeting just the sheet name part is what I am struggling with. Has anyone implemented such a use case?

```
key = businessFolder+businessFile
obj = s3.Object(inputBucket, key)
body = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('latin-1')
df=pd.read_excel(body, engine='openpyxl') #sheetName??
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the file from s3 and perform the operation

```
s3.Bucket(bucket_name).download_file(Key=key_name, Filename=file_name)
```